# Remove backslash when get url in pyrocms

Tags: laravel, pyrocms

I have problems when showing url, I use `{{ page.header_image.url }}` but the results is: `http://localhost:8000/\app/default/files-module/local/images/banner-ourpage.jpg`

Why I get the backslash in the url? It would be ok if no backslash.

I'm using windows and pyrocms 3.3

Comment: Do you add image banner-ourpage.jpg dynamically?

Comment: @MahfuzShishir yes, I add it using file field.

Comment: Show this code that you have implemented in your controller for uploading image.

Comment: @MahfuzShishir it's just a standard file field. I add a field in a certain page, the page also standard. then I want to print that field from view. my current code is {{ str_replace('\\','',page.header_image.url) }} which I believe that is wrong.

Comment: Are you up to date? 

If you can try and `dd($root)` just before this line for the image you're referring to: https://github.com/anomalylabs/streams-platform/blob/1.2/src/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L101

This service piggy backs off of Laravel's URL generator but we'll see what we're giving it. Maybe we need to trim first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed this is not making it into the `Image` class which is what I was assuming earlier. It was in the files adapter.

Your code is fine but I just realized there was a bug there for windows machines.

This should fix it: https://github.com/anomalylabs/local_storage_adapter-extension/commit/151b53be442e1851f2bd8a3b06b84cdbaeef9907